Yolov10 Model Category Alignment Issue
I am trying to set up my .yaml file to train my Yolov10 model. My custom data has 16 categories labelled 1-16, and I tried to have them correspond to the number of classes in the .yaml file in this format:
nc: 16
names:
1: class1
2: class2
3: class3
4: class4
5: class5
6: class6
7: class7
8: class8
9: class9
10: class10
11: class11
12: class12
13: class13
14: class14
15: class15
16: class16
However I'm getting this error:
RuntimeError: Dataset 'dataset.yaml' error ❌ '16-class dataset requires class indices 0-15, but you have invalid class indices 1-16 defined in your dataset YAML.'
I tried to make the list of classes in my .yaml file go from 0-15, but I get this error:
IndexKernel.cu:92: operator(): block: [111,0,0], thread: [90,0,0] Assertion -sizes[i] <= index && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds" failed.
I'm guessing this is because the actual data categories are labelled from 1 to 16. I haven't found much information about this problem elsewhere. Is this a data problem, or can I do something in the code to resolve this? Thank you in advance!
